# Set custom cell style in grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have a **custom** cell which has a similar look as the `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` style.

But when I 'fill' my UITableView, it looks similar to right sided image, so it's without the rounded edges. But I want it to look like the left sided image. How do I achieve this? Is it a property I can set in the xib?

[image]

Comment: Could you please show some of your code, and add some more details on exactly what you're doing? Then it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The left one is `initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped` style and the right one is `initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain`.

Use

```
[[NTCTableLayerOneViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

to initialize your tableView.
I can't find out where to set it in Interface Builder. Maybe it cannot.

Comment: @Xtudio if so, you need to set the first & last cell with radius, and set common cell's `backgroundView` or `contentView` with margins. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) you might find what you want. I think the default cell is enough.